# Autoloading: What are vendors and packages?

Tags: php, autoload, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

I just found out about [autoloading](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) and the [PSR-0 / PSR-4 standards](http://www.sitepoint.com/battle-autoloaders-psr-0-vs-psr-4/).

It keeps talking about "Vendors" and "package" names.

What exactly is a vendor?

And how should I for example organize my DB, User, and Product classes/models if I want to follow the standard?

Comment: If you create a new package, you are the vendor (or whatever you write there) and you can add a package name. These values are for distinguishes the different modules.

Comment: Basically a `vendor` is a provider for a "3rd party" library, a `package` is that library

Comment: so who would be the vendor for the PHPmailer package?

Comment: About vendor/packages you already got an answer. About application structure, PSR-0 is agnostic to what you are going to do with your classes; you may want to have a look at already existing structures [like Laravel or Symfony] in order to get some ideas.

Comment: If you look at PHPMailer on [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), its repository is `PHPMailer/PHPMailer`... so vendor is PHPMailer (before the `/`) and package is also PHPMailer (after the `/`)

Comment: Oh cool, so most times I should be able to follow the folder structure as it comes from github?

Comment: @olli - there may be exceptions, but that's generally the case; packagist uses the same principle

Comment: @MarkBaker why don't you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Vendor its for example ZendFramework, its a code provider. Package its module for example for Zend framework - Authentication or another folders in library\Zend dirrectory